# How can I convert my JSON response's key from snakecase to camel case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I just started using Rails for my web application's framework. Now I'm working on an API for a test project. I want the key of my API's JSON response to be camelcase instead of snakecase. How can I do that?

My JSON respond is something like this:

```
{"id":3,"name":"Bingo Gem", ..., "can_purchase":true,"shine":6,"created_at":"2014-07-31T06:34:37.917Z","updated_at":"2014-07-31T06:34:37.917Z","reviews":[]}
```

The response I expected:

```
{"id":3,"name":"Bingo Gem", ..., "canPurchase":true,"shine":6,"createdAt":"2014-07-31T06:34:37.917Z","updatedAt":"2014-07-31T06:34:37.917Z","reviews":[]}
```

Here's one of my controllers:

```
module Api
    module V1
        class PermataController < ApplicationController
            respond_to :json

            def index
                respond_with Permatum.all, :include => [:reviews]
            end

        end
    end
end
```

and routes.rb:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :schedules
      resources :permata
    end    
  end
```

Comment: Remember that snake_case_is_a_lot_easier_to_read comparedToTryingToReadCamelCase. Java programmers are used to camelCase but it's only used for class and module names in Ruby. Variables are snake_case. I'd argue that keys should remain as generated to avoid confusion when trying to correlate the JSON data with what your code is accessing from the parsed JSON object.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails, there is a method `camelize` in String class. Use it:

```
"can_purchase".camelize(:lower) #=> "canPurchase"
"created_at".camelize(:lower)   #=> "createdAt"
```